# crontab -e doesnt save

Tags: 16.04, cron

`crontab -e` opens up the editor selector. I choose 2 for nano. Edit the cron job. `[Ctrl]+O` to save. `[Ctrl]+Z` to exit. Then `crontab -l` to list and it tells me there are no cron jobs set for my user.

There is no `/etc/cron.allow` file and there is no `/etc/cron.deny`. My user is in the `/etc/shadow`.

I did a `apt-get remove cron && ape-get update && apt-get install cron` and it removed `clamtk clamtk-gnome cron ubuntu-standard` so I reinstalled them as well. Still no luck.

`sudo crontab -e` brings up an empty nano cron file with standard instructions for editing cron.

`sudo crontab -l` gives : no crontab for root

`crontab -e` brings up an empty nano cron file with standard instructions for editing cron.

`cronatb -l` gives : no crontab for user

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: and you used "sudo" on all commands?

Comment: yes I did use sudo . I even tried as root using sudo su.

Comment: `Crontab -e` and `crontab -l` show output from the user's crontab. If you used `sudo` with `crontab -e`, use `sudo crontab -l` to view and similarly and report back.

Comment: Perhaps there's something messed up in the mounting of your /tmp that's preventing the temporary crontab file from being written to the spool directory? Or /var is simply full?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I usually use `[Ctrl]+Z` to exit nano and it works just fine for everything I usually use, like: `sudo nano /etc/sources.list` or `sudo /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf`.

However for some reason when setting a crontab you must exit with `[Ctrl]+X` or the job will not be saved.